# React native :How programmatically trigger full screen with webview videos?

Tags: react-native, webview

I need a media player with my react native app where I can trigger full screen without user having to tap the full screen Icon on the video. I want trigger full screen mode programmatically or by default on clicking play ,how can I achieve this?
code

```
<WebView
 javaScriptEnabled={true}
 scrollEnabled={false}
 allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 
 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
 source={{uri: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/9yULZ8y1J-s?&autoplay=1&mute=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&fullscreen=1`}}
 style={styles.video}
/>
```

I tried above code but its not going full screen without user having to tap the full screen icon. Is there any other react native component where I can play videos and trigger full screen by default?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this package, that is also compatible with Expo : https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe